# Calculating values in SQL using two tables as references

Tags: sql-server

I'm not sure if I can explain this well, I have two tables, one with the following columns TotalLoan, InterestRate, Classification, LendingRates and the other has the following columns, SumLoan, Classification, LendingRates.

The first table, let's call it Loans has values of loans of specific users and their loan totals plus their interest rates while the other table has the sum of the total of loans based on the Classification and LendingRates. This means that if two users have the Classification Individual and LendingRate as 1-5years, their loans will be summed up. Let me try to visualize them, here is the Loans table.

[image]

and here is the second table containing the summations of the values using the lending rates and classification for grouping.

[image]

For the sake of simplicity and also the fact that I'm dealing with real bank values here and I'm not supposed to share the company data online I created a fake summary on Excel, this is not the real data. The real data contains thousands of rows. So the formula is

(InterestRate * TotalLoan)/Sum of total.

Thereby for Individuals with Overdraft, you'll take the first expression to be

(12*34555)/12221222
then
(14*22322)/12221222
then
(6/76772)/76772 and so on...

Anyone has an idea how I can do this in Microsoft SQL. I'm seriously stumped here.

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: How is the 2 table related ? i see 5 rows in `table 1` but only 4 in `table 2`

Comment: It there an issue there?
(12*34555)/ **12221222** then (14*22322)/ **12221222** then (6/76772)/ **76772** and so on...
And, what is the expected result?

Comment: Sorry but it seems I struggled with it till I got the answer. All I had to do was do a join to match the Classifications and LendingRates, get the value from the second table using that join and use it to divide...